# Android dynamic gridview

Tags: android, gridview

How to control the size of cell in dynamic `gridview` 
to resize the cell item to take `wrap_content` by Java?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
grid.setNumColumns(8);
grid.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
grid.setColumnWidth(100);
//grid.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
grid.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);
//grid.getMeasuredWidth();
grid.setMinimumWidth(100);
grid.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
grid.setAdapter(adp);
balance_layout.addView(grid);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690144/how-can-i-force-a-gridview-to-use-the-whole-screen-regardless-of-display-size read this topic, it might provide some answers

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.getChildAt(position).getLayoutParams.width = YOUR_SIZE;
```

You may need to call

```
grid.invalidate();
```

to force grid redraw itself.

I would suggest you use some library to let you have a feature like you want or create a custom adapter and chage width with this technique in getView method.