# Stretch GridView to fit full screen

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to stretch my `GridView`, which contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside each grid, to cover the complete screen of a phone.

I have already tried lots of solutions given online, but none of them worked for me. Some of the answers which I have already tried are:

[How can I force a GridView to use the whole screen (regardless of display size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690144/how-can-i-force-a-gridview-to-use-the-whole-screen-regardless-of-display-size)

[android How to stretch rows in the gridview to fill screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067449/android-how-to-stretch-rows-in-the-gridview-to-fill-screen)

Here is my code:

**activity_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gaming">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/categoryGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**category_grid_single.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridImageView"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridImageView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_category_grid_single, null);
        grid.setMinimumHeight(mheight/3);//mheight is the Height of the screen

    } else {
        grid = convertView;
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridImageViewText);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridImageView);
    textView.setText(category[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(ImageId[position]);
    return grid;
}
```

I am trying to achieve a `GridView` similar to below Image. But currently after setting up my `GridView` I am getting empty space in the bottom. If there is any better way to achieve it other than the `GridView` then please suggest that too.

[image]

This is what I am getting

[image]

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your text view do  android:layout_width="match_parent"  if that doesn't work give weight as 1 and see

Comment: @Redman, I didn't work. Same result.

Comment: can you keep the screenshot of how you are getting it might help?

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049803/6952986

Comment: @JuLes, I already tried it. Did not work.

Comment: is height the problem?

Comment: try using debug, check the height before and after setting the `grid.setMinimumHeight`

Comment: The picture above that you use as an example actually *does* have extra space at the bottom (you have to look closely). I assume you want the views to take up the entire space of the screen? Will there always be six views in the grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html), instead of a `GridView`, by using the [`layout_columnWeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/gridlayout/R.attr.html#layout_columnWeight) and [`layout_rowWeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/gridlayout/R.attr.html#layout_rowWeight) attributes. `GridLayout` was added in API level 14, but these attributes were not added until API level 21. But you can make use of the `GridLayout` as well as the `layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight` attributes back to API level 7 by using the [v7 GridLayout Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7):

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
```

Then, all you have to do is make sure every cell in the `GridLayout` has an equal `layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/black_alpha_26">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="YouTube"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Videos"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="VR Apps"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/black_alpha_26">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="VR Movies"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/black_alpha_26">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="VR Games"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Shop"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the result I got:

[image: Test GridLayout]

Answer (score 1):

Checklist to recap main points for the grid described in [Bryan's nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40641723/2162226):

1. Add the compile directive

   - *currently using:* `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'`
2. Update the layout to be `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

   - *watch out here, I missed this at first and **made the mistake** of omitting the full package name*
3. Set `app:columnCount="2"`
4. Set each grid element with:

   ```
   app:layout_columnWeight="1" 
   app:layout_rowWeight="1"
   ```

---

**demo xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="m1"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="m2"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="m3"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="m4"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```